# Notation for indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The notation $\int{f(x)}\,dx$ is commonly used to denote the set of ALL antiderivatives of the function $f$. Is it wrong to use the notation $\int{f(x)}\,dx$ to denote a single antiderivative of the function $f$ without the constant of integration $c$?

I saw many instances where the notation $\int{f(x)}\,dx$ is used to denote a single antiderivative with the constant of integration omitted. For example to evaluate $\int {xe^x}\,dx$, some textbooks wrote $v=\int\,dv=\int{e^x}\,dt=e^x$, without the constant of integration. For example, to solve the differential equation $y'+\frac{2}{t}y=e^t$ by using an integrating factor, some textbooks wrote $\mu(t)=\exp(\int{2/t}\,dt)=t^2$, without a constant of integration.

Comment: @samjoe My question is about notation not about constant of integration. My question is "Can the symbol $\int{f(x)}\,dx$ be used to denote both "a single antiderivative of $f$" and "the set of ALL antiderivatives of $f$".

Answer (score 1):

For your integrating factor question, it really does not matter.  When you are finding an integrating factor, you multiply every term in the differential equation by this factor.  Including the $+C$ or not, means multiplying the whole equation by $e^{C}$, but this does not really matter as this constant term will cancel out.

It is usually common practice to always include the constant of integration, but it may sometimes be omitted for simplification purposes.